# Use #text on JSON to convert on XML using Json.org

Tags: java, xml, json, groovy, soapui

I'm converting a json string into a XML by using json.org, everything is ok about this because I know how to use the library but I have a problem, I'd like to be able to convert from JSON to XML something like this:

XML:

```
<ocs:price exponent="-1">2</ocs:price>
```

JSON:

```
"ocs:price": {
            "-exponent": "-1",
            "#text": "2"
          }
```

If I use json.org with this I'm getting the following when I have everything converted to XML:

```
<ocs:price>
   <#text>2</#text>
   <exponent>-1</exponent>
</ocs:price>
```

That's not what I'm looking for, How could convert 
`<ocs:price exponent="-1">2</ocs:price>` into a JSON value string by using JSON.org library?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Would you like this way, groovy script follows

```
import net.sf.json.JSON
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer

String str = '''{
  "ocs:price": {
    "@exponent": "-1",
    "#text": "2"
  }
}'''
JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON( str )
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer()
xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility( false )
String xml = xmlSerializer.write( json )
System.out.println(xml)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! by the way, do you happen to know How I can eliminate from the output, strings such as "json_class="object" , etc? I can do it by doing a replace but you know.. It's not well "done" 100%.

Comment: I'd like to do this by using json.org library because the library on this example doesn't make the conversion of arrays properly